# Porque al no ingresar una fecha me guarda la fecha del dia de hoy por default?

Tags: laravel, laravel-7, carbon

Mi vista contiene un formulario donde hay algunos campos opcionales para fechas. Si yo omito esos campos en vez de mostrarme el registro vacío, me pone por default el valor de la fecha del día actual.

De la siguiente manera estoy pasandole data y cargandolos en mi formulario a algunos campos de fecha.

```
<div class="form-group col-md-2">
                      <label for="entry3">Fecha de Ingreso</label>
                      <input type="text" name="entry3" id="entry3" class="form-control form-control-sm"  placeholder="Ingreso a Laboratorio" readonly>
                    </div>
                      
                    <div class="form-group col-md-2">
                      <label for="deliver3">Fecha de Devolucion</label>
                      <input type="text" name="deliver3" id="deliver3" class="form-control form-control-sm"  placeholder="Entrega al Cliente" readonly>
                    </div>
```

De esta manera estan definidos los campos en mi metodo store en el controlador:

```
$ticket->entry3 = Carbon::parse ( $request->entry3)->toDateString();
$ticket->deliver3 = Carbon::parse ( $request->deliver3)->toDateString();
```

y de la misma manera en mi metodo de update.

Y asi estan definidos los campos en mi migration:

```
$table->date('entry3')->nullable();
$table->date('deliver3')->nullable();
```

Ademas estoy usando la librería de bootstrap 4 para el formato:

```
$('#entry').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
        
    });
    $('#deliver').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });

    $('#entry2').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
        
    });
    $('#deliver2').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });

    $('#entry3').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
        
    });
    $('#deliver3').datepicker({
        uiLibrary: 'bootstrap4',
        format: 'dd-mm-yyyy'
    });
```

Como puedo hacer para que aparezcan vacíos mis campos si no ingreso nada, es como si por default me guarda la fecha actual, y yo quiero que el campo este nulo si no se ingresa nada.

Comment: No es algo por default, `Carbon::parse(null)` retorna un objeto Carbon. Bastaría un condicional para no asignar ningún valor

Comment: Tienes algun ejemplo de como aplicarlo? @porloscerrosΨ

Comment: El ejemplo sería el que pusieron en la respuesta de abajo

Answer (score 0):

En el método store de tu controlador:

```
if ($ticket->entry3) {
    $ticket->entry3 = Carbon::parse ($request->entry3)->toDateString();
}
if ($ticket->deliver3) {
    $ticket->deliver3 = Carbon::parse ($request->deliver3)->toDateString();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Buen día,

Únicamente te hace falta usar una condición para asignar la fecha ingresada o asignar un string vacío en caso de que el campo esté vacío

```
if ($ticket->entry3) {
    $ticket->entry3 = Carbon::parse ($request->entry3)->toDateString();
} else {
    $ticket->entry3 = "";
}
if ($ticket->deliver3) {
    $ticket->deliver3 = Carbon::parse ($request->deliver3)->toDateString();
} else {
    $ticket->deliver3 = "";
}
```

Como es una tarea muy simple, yo utilizaría el [Operador ternario](https://www.php.net/ternary#language.operators.comparison.ternary) (También conocido como operador condicional) en lugar de "if" para reducir el número de líneas de código.

```
$ticket->entry3 ? $ticket->entry3 = Carbon::parse ($request->entry3)->toDateString() : $ticket->entry3 = $ticket->entry3 = "";

$ticket->deliver3 ? $ticket->deliver3 = Carbon::parse ($request->deliver3)->toDateString() : $ticket->deliver3 = "";
```